# cypress's function "type()" doesn't do anything

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I have this component StyledInput:

```
<script setup>
import MyInputfrom '../MyInput/MyInput.vue';

const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    fieldData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
});
</script>

<template>
    <MyInput
        v-bind="props"
        @update:modelValue="$emit('update:modelValue', $event)"
    ></MyInput>
</template>

<style></style>
```

And MyInput:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    fieldData: {
        // example : v$.username
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
});
const { modelValue, label, fieldData, ...propsToTransmit } = props;
</script>

<template>
    <v-text-field
        :value="modelValue"
        :label="label"
        :error-messages="fieldData.$errors.map((e) => e.$message)"
        @input="
            fieldData.$touch;
            $emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value);
        "
        @blur="fieldData.$touch"
        variant="outlined"
        v-bind="propsToTransmit"
    ></v-text-field>
</template>

<style></style>
```

I use in a form StyledInput like this :

```
const formData: any = reactive({
    mytext: '',
});
const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, formData);

<StyledInput 
    v-model="formData.mytext"
    label="My text"
    :fieldData="v$.mytext"
/>
```

And it works perfectly.

So I used cypress to test StyledInput this way :

```
const config = {
    props: {
        modelValue: 'test',
        label: 'test label',
        fieldData: {
            $errors: [],
            $touch: () => {},
        },
    },
    global: {
        plugins: [vuetify],
    },
};

describe('<StyledInput />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        cy.mount(StyledInput , config);
    });

    it('refreshes the value of the variable when we type in it', () => {
        var myVar = 'hey';
        cy.mount(StyledInput, {
            ...config,
            props: {
                ...config.props,
                modelValue: myVar,
            },
        });
        cy.get('input').type('texttest').should('have.value', 'texttest');
        expect(myVar).to.equal('texttest');
    });
});
```

The first test works, the second doesn't. Result "assertexpected <input#input-0.v-field__input> to have value texttest, but the value was test"
From the iframe showing the view, I see that the input doesn't have "texttest" written, but only "hey".

This is pretty much a simple test, I don't understand what's wrong. any lead? Thank you

Update:

```
cy.get('input').type('texttest');
cy.wait(500);
cy.get('input').should('have.value', 'texttest');
```

Doesn't work either.

Comment: According to the documentation it's not safe to chain further command that rely on the subject to type. So you might want to rewrite the test. 
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type

Comment: @ToonKrijthe tried (and put in post) -> doesn't change anything